# How to detect event of end drawing circle on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
var markers = mapController.gMarkers;
    var lng = markers.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
        // Add circle overlay and bind to marker
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: mapController.mapGl.map,
            radius: 160930,    // 100 miles in metres
            fillColor: '#AA0000'
        });
        circle.bindTo('center', markers[i], 'position');
        mapController.gCircles.push(circle);
    }
```

Rise a method in the end of cycle does not help. It happens earlier than all circles is visible.

I want to get the event when all circles is already drawn and visible on a map.
Init code:

```
`//check for suportting WebGL
    if (!Detector.webgl) {
        Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
        return;
    }
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
    var options = {
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom: 3,
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.19595526752781, -96.67078125),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        draggableCursor: 'url(pcursor.png) 16 16, default'
    };

    mapController = new WebGlMap(mapElement, options);
    var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager();
    drawingManager.setMap(mapController.mapGl.map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function (circle) {
        alert('hit!');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (event) {
        alert('hit!');
    });

    //mapController.gPolygons = [];
    mapController.gMarkers = [];
    mapController.gCircles = [];`
```

Comment: What does the rest of you code look like?  Are you doing this on initialization?  Have you tried the 'idle' event?

Comment: Events registering in the init method.

Comment: How can help idle event? It doesn't rise after drawing of circles.

Comment: Still need more context.  Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), preferably in your question, but a supplemental jsfiddle that exhibits the problem wouldn't hurt.  If the circles are being added to the map in the initialize function, then the idle event _might_ help.  Still can't tell what you are trying to do or what your actual problem is.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ymPCX/27/

Comment: I need add circles after click on a button, not on init function. I'm trying to count how many seconds take to draw all circles.

Comment: Sorry.  I don't see any button in your code. (or in your fiddle)

Comment: Interesting.  Doesn't display if I have the debugger open in Chrome (and it was off the bottom of the screen the first time I looked).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check the circle is visible?

```
circle.getVisible();
```

At the Api reference they write "Returns whether this circle is visible on the map."

if getVisible() returns false you have to wait. 
But it could be that it will only return you the visibility u have at to the object itself

a other way is to use a workearound with the center_changed event ... add all your circle and then change the center of the last one (or a not visible help circle) if googlemaps add the circle one by one, the change would happen after all is done, at this event u can call ur stuff

edit:
i have found a event u will like "circlecomplete"
it is a event of the google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager class
i think that will do what u are trying to to

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't help. get Visible() and visible return true before it drawn on a map, manipulation with events doesn't helps too.

Comment: have u tried the DrawingManager and the event circlecomplete ?

Comment: Yes I have, google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function (e) {
            alert('hit one!');
        }); overlaycomplete event tried too.

Comment: i guess u have done it this way: [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawing?hl=de)
so ur drawingManager looks like this:`var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager();
drawingManager.setMap(map);`
if so it should fire the event ....mmh maybe it is and old api?

Comment: Events like 'circle complete' or 'overlaycomplete',registered in this way rise only if you draw circle by drawing panel.